# Encode/encrypt XML in HTML value in of a hidden field.

Tags: java, xml, encryption

I need to have a `XML String` in a HTML value of a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="anyId" name="anyName" 
value="<?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;...?>
```

I want to encode/encrypt the XML String before sending to the frontend because it should not be a normal readable text.

The encoding and decoding will be done in java.

Can anyone tell me which is the best way to do it and which frameworks/tools... I can use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the default way is base64. It is not really encrypted but also not simply readable. But anybody who knows base64 can decode it.
In Java 8 it would be as simple as:

```
String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("blabla".getBytes("utf-8"));
```

And

```
String base64decodedString = new 
    String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("dGVzdA=="), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then you don't even need to do the &quot stuff.
If you want to do real encryption because it's really secret stuff you have to add the exncrption in between getting this bytes of the string and creating the base64 string. Either way you end up with base64 because it's imho the simplest way to convert binary to string.

Comment: But Base64 is actually an encoding technique not an encryption technique. Try some encryption techniques like RSA/AES.